# Counter-example wanted for a conjecture on polynomials

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, polynomials, examples-counterexamples, jensen-inequality

it's a conjecture on polynomials with positive coefficient :

> Let $x,y>0$ then we have :
>   $$\frac{x^2f(x)+y^2f(y)}{xf(x)+yf(y)}\leq \frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}\frac{f\Big(\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}\Big)}{f\Big(\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}\Big)}$$
>   Where ($k$ a natural number): $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k$$
>   And :$$a_k>0  \quad\forall k\geq0$$

The problem of my previous inequality [An inequality for polynomials with positives coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388172/an-inequality-for-polynomials-with-positives-coefficients) was the fixed coefficient $2$ . To recall I just apply Jensen's inequality on the denominator and the numerator of the LHS .

Furthermore I have tried exotic polynomials like :

$$f(x)=\sin(1)+ex^3+x^{10}$$

I have tried also monomials .

Polynomials like :

$$f(x)=1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{3}x^2+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}x^{n-1}$$

Works also .

And the counter-example $f(x)=1+x^{10}$ works .

So my question : Have you a counter-example ?

Thanks a lot for sharing your time and knowledge .

Ps:I work with Pari-Gp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{Counterexample}$$[$$\boxed{x=0.5,\quad y=1.01,\quad f(y):=1+0.0001(y+y^2+\cdots+y^{99})+y^{100}}$$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hsoxc8a2pt) $$\frac{0.5^2f\left(0.5\right)+1.01^{2}f\left(1.01\right)}{0.5f\left(0.5\right)+1.01f\left(1.01\right)}>0.95,\quad\frac{0.5^2+1.01^{2}}{0.5+1.01}\cdot\frac{f\left(\frac{0.5^{3}+1.01^{3}}{0.5^2+1.01^{2}}\right)}{f\left(\frac{0.5^2+1.01^{2}}{0.5+1.01}\right)}<0.85$$